# If statement in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to create a formula that allows me to look for values within a row to identify them on a reference worksheet. For example, `=if(Ref!A1=1,"Value")` but if A1=0 THEN go to B1 so `=if(B1=1,"Value2")` and continue doing so for 5 more cells within the same row.

I've tried with several formulas but ended up stuck with this one: `=IF('Ref'!J2=1,"5",SEARCH('Ref'!K2,IF('Ref'!K2=1,"2",SEARCH('Ref'!L2,IF('Ref'!L2=1,"3",SEARCH('Ref'!M2,IF('Ref'!M2=1,"1",SEARCH('Ref'!N2,IF('Ref'!N2=1,"4")))))))))`

I would appreciate some help. I provided the next image as a reference. It displays the reference worksheet and the values that I need to search.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX/MATCH

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Ref'!$1:$1),MATCH(1,'Ref'!2:2,0)),"")
```

This will return the value in the first row where the second row = 1.

You can limit the scope to only include the range you want (based on your picture)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Ref'!$A$1:$E$1),MATCH(1,'Ref'!$A2:$E2,0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks. For example, let's take row 6. What I need is to return the value "var3" as both of the previous cells were not 1. The "index/match" function would still help me with that?

Comment: yes it would do just that. @Phil  It looks for the first `1` and returns the value in row 1 at that point. for row `6` the formula would be: `=IFERROR(INDEX('Ref'!$A$1:$E$1),MATCH(1,'Ref'!$A6:$E6,0)),"")`

Comment: I just got it right. Cheers, mate. I made it a bit more complex adding the if statement, but it's now working smoothly.